# I'm wondering what the C# compiler is actually waiting on, when doing a compile in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, .net-core, intel

```
I have a Windows machine with the following specs:
   48 GB Ram (24 GB free)
   8700K CPU, overclocked 27% & stable. 4.29 Ghz
   7.5 GB/sec SSDs for the disk
   1 Gbps Internet
 2070 Nvidia Graphics card.
```

Most of that doesn't matter, this seems to apply to all sorts of machines...

I'm doing a full build on my project, which is rather large.. Looking at the performance tab, I'm consistently seeing 38% CPU use... 2% Disk use... 49% RAM use, 0% Ethernet use...  (the entire build never topped 40% CPU usage!)

I'm wondering why the CPU isn't slammed during this time, is the C# compiler not doing multithreaded compiling?   Even if it isn't, I should see one core that is totally slammed... There shouldn't be situations where it is waiting for (What??) enough that is only using 38% of the CPU...

I did a rebuild just now, and I'm seeing 100% CPU usage.. At the start, but the end of the build:
[image]

I could see it using up a few CPU Cycles waiting on some disk I/O, but 60% of the CPU when the disks are screaming fast? (AND idle?)

Years ago, Machines would get totally slammed by the compilers..  Of course, it is almost impossible to get Apple Silicon slammed to the point of UI slow down (I've tried, machine always responds just fine), but that is another subject..  And is due to their hardware design.

Example build, from start to finish: (it started right at the start of the graph, and ended right at the end of the graph, and 20% of my CPU is being used by other processes..)

[image]

Update: Resource Monitor Graphs:
[image]

Comment: Difficult to say w/o being able to compare. This is for example what I get when I'm fully rebuilding this (https://github.com/smourier/DirectN compile may fail the first time) https://i.imgur.com/L81FKFM.png (disk usage is quite low, I run over the new Dev Drive thing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-drive/) If you have a big project to compare, we can do some tests

Comment: That's a processor that supports 12 threads, one thread represents 8.3% load.  How you got it that high is unclear, compilation is an inherently single-threaded operation.  Other processes running, perhaps.  Creating a .exe or .dll tends to get the anti-malware product excited for example.

Comment: The number of cores utilized is related to the number of separate compilation units included in your build, with C++ the build system can spawn a separate compiler process for each one, with C# they're handled by a single process but can still proceed in parallel.

Comment: *Even if it isn't, I should see one core that is totally slammed.* - The graph you're looking at can't show you that.  Open Resource Monitor instead of Task Manager to get per-(logical)-core load graphs.  (But last I heard, Windows' scheduler still doesn't do a good job at keeping a task on the same core, so even a single-threaded workload gets migrated a lot, suffering lots of cache misses... and showing up as light load across all your cores unless you look on a pretty short timescale.)

Comment: Your Task Manager screenshots shows that it was coming pretty close to keeping all your physical cores busy (close to 50% load); perhaps it chooses to only start as many parallel compile tasks as there are physical cores, if it doesn't scale well with hyperthreading?  But probably not, might just be the limits of parallelism after some early highly-parallel stuff (maybe parsing multiple source files.)

Comment: Well, I did a 'rebuild all' and got 100% utilization on the CPU for the full build...   My guess was that maybe it was smart enough to say:  I'm building 49 projects... I can build the first one that everyone depends on, but then, after that one is built, I can build 3 at once... and then once those are built, I can build 8 at once.. then 10... (or whatever) as the graph of project dependencies should allow that.  And maybe with a single project change it is very limited.  This is C#, so it seems it should be able to handle the multithreading a bit better..

Comment: (I have about 20% consistently used CPU by other processes, and that graph is pretty straight if I am not doing anything else..), so I guess that with 12 logical CPUs, if it goes up to 36%, that means it is hitting 16% more CPU used, or 2 threads being able to run..   It just seems like the compiler could build multiple things that are not dependent on each other at the same time.. I.E. two source files in the same project that don't depend on each other?